# SSIS execute sql task get value from a query statement

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS 2008 and put a simple query (not proc) in an execute sql task (control flow). The query generate one column with a single value, what I am trying to do is based on this value to decide whether to do the following tasks. I tried mapping the value to a variable in the parameter mapping. I tried direction Output/Return value etc but all failed. The query takes no parameter. I know probably I can create a proc with a output parameter to be mapped to a variable but just wondering if there is other options (e.g. not creating proc, it's very simple query)?

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear, as I understand it your SQL task will give you an output and based on this you want to change the control flow to do different tasks? If that's the case then change the result set to `Single Row` and then that will output it to a variable. You can then use this variable to change the workflow.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! That's exactly what I am trying to do. Please put your comment in the answer and I will choose yours as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to change the SQL Task to give a Result Set on a 'Single Row', you can then output that result set to a variable.

From here you can use the constraints within the Control Flow to execute different tasks based upon what the outcome variable will be; for example:

[image: Expression Constraint]